# Consulta SQL, colocar resultados horizontal

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente query

```
DECLARE @Identidad VARCHAR(20)
SET @Identidad='1154789711245'

SELECT
 ,c.NombreCliente                 
 ,c.IdentidadCliente              
 ,ccr.NumeroCuenta                
 ,Firma.NombreFirmante       

FROM dbo.Clientes c
INNER JOIN dbo.Cuentas ccr ON ccr.ClientId = c.ClientId 

OUTER APPLY (
SELECT DISTINCT
c2.NombreCliente,
CASE WHEN c2.TipoClienteId IN (8,9) THEN (
                                    SELECT TOP 1  c4.TaxCode
                                    FROM dbo.ClienteConexion AS cl1 WITH (NOLOCK)
                                    INNER JOIN dbo.Clientes AS c4 ON c4.ClientId = cl1.ClientId2
                                    WHERE cl1.ClientId1 = C2.ClientId
                                         )
ELSE c2.IdentidadCliente 
END  AS Identidad

FROM dbo.Cuentas AS ccr2 WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.Clientes AS c2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON c2.ClientId=ccr2.ClientId
INNER JOIN dbo.CuentasAutorizaciones cca WITH (NOLOCK) ON cca.CustomerContractRelationId = ccr2.CustomerContractRelationId
INNER JOIN dbo.TiposAutorizacionCuentas ccat WITH (NOLOCK) ON ccat.AuthorizatonTypeId = cca.AuthorizatonTypeId
WHERE ccr2.ContractNumber=ccr.ContractNumber AND ccr2.CustomerContractRelationTypeId <> 1
)Firma


WHERE c.IdentidadCliente=@Identidad
  AND cct.ContractStatusId=2
  AND sct.SystemContractTypeID IN (3,30)
```

En el cual obtengo el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que me tira es las cuentas que tiene un cliente y los firmantes autorizados de cada cuenta, como se ve en la imagen el cliente **Empresa 1** tiene 2 cuentas y me detalla todos los usuarios que son firmantes de las 2 cuentas, la cosa es que quiero que me salga únicamente 2 registros de las 2 cuentas y en el campo **NombreFirmante** ahí estén todos los nombres de todos los firmantes concatenados con una coma(,)

muestro una imagen del resultado esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si debo usar UNPIVOT pero no se como aplicarlo

Alguien que me ayude

Comment: Nop. No es un pivot, pero la respuesta depende de la versión del motor de bd que estés utilizando. Si es SQLServer 2017, o posterior, tienes [STRING_AGG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). De lo contrario, tienes que utilizar magia negra y [STUFF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) como en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-before-2017). Suerte.

Comment: La herramienta que utilizo es Sql Server Management Studio 2012

Comment: Uhmm.. El SQLServer Management Studio, como su nombre lo indica, es para **gestionar** el motor de bases de datos pero **no** es el motor en sí. Necesitas saber la versión de SQLServer (el motor). Puedes hacer un `Select @@VERSION` para saber cuál versión tienes. Si es `14.x` puedes utilizar `string_agg`, si es menor que eso, deberás utilizar `stuff`

Comment: 11.0.6260 es la version que estoy utilizando

Comment: Dada la versión de tu motor de base de datos tendrias que usar el stuff y el xml para realizar lo que deseas, te anexo una url https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/